# Setting elements in a big vector in R

Tags: r, gmp

I'm working with vectors in R, storing bigz objects ([GMP package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gmp/index.html)). It works fine when the vector is not too big (up to 200 elems), but when the vector grows, the performance decrease dramatically.

Trying to get where the bottleneck is, I execute my programm with the `profvis` library, and I get that the problem is the next piece of code:

```
res <- as.bigz(rep(0, length(resT))) #resT is a list of bigz of length 600
res[[1]] <- sum.bigz(a_bigz_elem, another_bigz_elem)
i <- 1
while (i <= length(resT) - 1) {
    res[[i + 1]] <- sum.bigz(resT[[i + 1]], resE[[i + 1]])
    i <- i + 1
}
```

and more specifically, in the 5th line (the elem assignment in the list).

I know this solution is better than a growing vector, i.e. `res <- c(res, sum.bigz(resT[[i + 1]], resE[[i + 1]]))`, but I'm pretty sure there is a more efficient way to do the assignment.

I've read related post in SO and the [Advanced R](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/) reference documentation, but nothing improves my performance. Any idea how can it be improved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With

```
res <- as.bigz(rep(0, length(resT))) #resT is a list of bigz of length 600
```

you are *not* creating a `list`. When you change it to:

```
res <- as.list(as.bigz(rep(0, length(resT))))
```

you create a list and the execution time should be reduced.

A reproducible example would look like:

```
library(gmp)

resT  <- as.list(urand.bigz(600, seed=0))
resE  <- as.list(urand.bigz(600, seed=1))
a_bigz_elem  <- resT[[1]]
another_bigz_elem  <- resE[[1]]

res <- as.list(as.bigz(rep(0, length(resT))))
res[[1]] <- sum.bigz(a_bigz_elem, another_bigz_elem)
i <- 1
while (i <= length(resT) - 1) {
  res[[i + 1]] <- sum.bigz(resT[[i + 1]], resE[[i + 1]])
  i <- i + 1
}
```

Comment: You are completely right, that speeds up the execution a lot! I've missunderstood the ``as.list`` function. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a concise way, a bit more efficient than @GKi's solution:

```
mapply(sum.bigz, resT, resE, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
```

#### Benchmarks:

```
library(gmp)

resT_list  <- as.list(urand.bigz(1000, seed=0))
resE_list  <- as.list(urand.bigz(1000, seed=1))

f1 <- function(){
  a_bigz_elem  <- resT_list[[1]]
  another_bigz_elem  <- resE_list[[1]]
  res <- as.list(as.bigz(rep(0, length(resT_list))))
  res[[1]] <- sum.bigz(a_bigz_elem, another_bigz_elem)
  i <- 1
  while (i <= length(resT_list) - 1) {
    res[[i + 1]] <- sum.bigz(resT_list[[i + 1]], resE_list[[i + 1]])
    i <- i + 1
  }
  res
}

f2 <- function(){
  mapply(sum.bigz, resT_list, resE_list, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
}

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(
  f1 = f1(),
  f2 = f2(),
  times = 10
)
# Unit: milliseconds
# expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
#   f1 15.27488 16.48450 19.84019 17.51613 25.25338 28.10120    10   b
#   f2 11.83838 12.21875 13.30705 12.87080 14.37143 15.75504    10  a
```

Comment: ``mapply`` function seems fine, but I need to set the first item of the list with a different result